# Can not load image for prediction from json file while using python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am developing a simple web app that is supposed to load image from json and then make some predictions. Here's my code in html and python:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Predict app </title>
    <style>
        * {
            font-size:30px;
        }
    </style>    
</head> 
<body>
    <input id="image-selector" type="file">
    <button id="predict-button"> Predict</button>

    <p style="font-weight:bold">Predictions</p>
    <p> Jablko <span id="apple-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> Banan <span id="banana-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> Marchewka <span id="carrot-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> Ogorek <span id="cucumber-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> Cytryna <span id="lemon-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> Pomarancza <span id="orange-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> Gruszka <span id="pear-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> Papryka <span id="peper-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> Ziemniak <span id="potato-prediction"></span></p>
    <p> Pomidor <span id="tomato-prediction"></span></p>
    <img id="selected-image" src=""/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let base64Image;
        $("#image-selector").change(function(){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
            let dataURL = reader.result;
            $('#selected-image').attr("src", dataURL);
            base64Image = dataURL.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            console.log(base64Image);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL($("#image-selector")[0].files[0]);
            $("#apple-prediction").text("");
            $("#banana-prediction").text("");
            $("#carrot-prediction").text("");
            $("#cucumber-prediction").text("");
            $("#lemon-prediction").text("");
            $("#orange-prediction").text("");
            $("#pear-prediction").text("");
            $("#peper-prediction").text("");
            $("#potato-prediction").text("");
            $("#tomato-prediction").text("");
            });

            $("#predict-button").click(function(event){
                    let message = {
                    image:base64Image
                    }
                    console.log(message);
                    $.post("http://192.168.8.102:5000/predict", JSON.stringify(message), function(response){
                    $("#apple-prediction").text(response.prediction.apple.toFixed(6));
                    $("#banana-prediction").text(response.prediction.banana.toFixed(6));
                    $("#carrot-prediction").text(response.prediction.carrot.toFixed(6));
                    $("#cucumber-prediction").text(response.prediction.cucumber.toFixed(6));
                    $("#lemon-prediction").text(response.prediction.lemon.toFixed(6));
                    $("#orange-prediction").text(response.prediction.orange.toFixed(6));
                    $("#pear-prediction").text(response.prediction.pear.toFixed(6));
                    $("#peper-prediction").text(response.prediction.pepper.toFixed(6));
                    $("#potato-prediction").text(response.prediction.potato.toFixed(6));
                    $("#tomato-prediction").text(response.prediction.tomato.toFixed(6));
                    console.log(response);
                    });
                    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>



import base64
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import io
import keras
#from keras import load_weights
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
import keras.preprocessing.image
from flask import request, jsonify, Flask
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

app = Flask(__name__)


def get_model():
    global model
    model=tf.keras.models.load_model('fc_model1.h5')
    model.load_weights('model_grocery.h5')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph
    print("** Model loaded!")


def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = keras.img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    return image

print("**Loading model")
get_model()

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(200, 200))
    prediction = model.predict(processed_image).tolist()

    response = {
        'prediction': {
            'apple': prediction[0][0],
            'banana': prediction[0][1],
            'lemon': prediction[0][2],
            'orange': prediction[0][3],
            'pear': prediction[0][4],
            'carrot': prediction[0][5],
            'cucumber': prediction[0][6],
            'pepper': prediction[0][7],
            'potato': prediction[0][8],
            'tomato': prediction[0][9],
        }
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

However, while opening an image I get the error:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000023B89E880A0>.
```

I am using flask and my model is already on server.
I tried opening image in other ways but nothing has helped. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback? It is most likely coming from your `image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))` line but I'm not sure if it's `Image.open()` or `io.BytesIO()` throwing the error.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have updated the code in post